# Why CPU is used by kernel in simple for loop

Tags: python, kernel

I'm trying to understand user CPU time and system CPU time but still confused about the difference. I understood that system CPU time is time spent by kernel but can not find when CPU is used by kernel in my code.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: a = np.zeros((3000, 4000), dtype=np.int64)
   ...: b = np.zeros((3000, 4000), dtype=np.int64)
   ...:

In [2]: %%time
   ...: b[:] = a[:]
   ...:
CPU times: user 12 ms, sys: 24 ms, total: 36 ms
Wall time: 38.5 ms
```

Why copying value from array `a` to `b` does the CPU usage need to be by kernel? It is just a simple loop iterating each element of `a` and `b` which can be done in user mode, isn't it?

Comment: You could use `strace` to see the system calls the program made.

Comment: Every interaction with any system resource involves the kernel in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Then does it mean that kernel can be involved even if there is no explicit system call?